# How to increase column filter character limit of DataTable.js?

Tags: datatable

I was spending a whole day to find a way to keep the column filter searching regardless the number of characters being inputted. At the moment, i.e the date column stops filtering after the **12th character** is entered as I have a custom search condition which requires a longer than a **12-character** input.

The link below is what it looks like what I have implemented

`https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html`

In my case, I try to get it work on the Start Date filter to allow date range filtering. For instance, when you search

`ie. 2012/09/26`

it returns one record and that is correct. Console log also

and when you search

`ie. 2012/09/26 2012`

it doesn't display any records nor trigger any keypress events (ie. **`$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()`**) which perform filtering after `2012/09/26 2` ie. `012...`. The function is only triggered for the first 12 characters.

You can try it on jsfiddle.net/4udkchf8/3 which I've just created so that you can replicate the issue. When you enter upto to 2008/09/26 20, you see the value is logged to the console but any characters after than ie. '2008/09/26 201...`.

Can anyone shed light on how to achieve that?

Regards,

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] for this? I have not hit this limitation using filter input strings - including filters for date/time data. I have tried with the global filter input and with custom column filter inputs, also.

Comment: @andrewjames FYI, I've updated the question

Comment: When I visit the example you provide, and I type `ie. 2012/09/26 2012` into the `Start Date` filter, it displays zero records, as expected. There is no date in that column containing the text `ie.` - so there are no records selected. It is working correctly. If I type `auth jun` into the `Position` search field, it finds 1 record, because there is one value containing _both_ `auth` _and_ `jun` - that value is `Junior Technical Author`.

Comment: I suppose you did not literally mean `ie. 2012/09/26 2012`. I guess you meant `2012/09/26 2012`. But even in that case, it works as expected. It finds 1 record. I am not seeing your problem using that example. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: as i mentioned in the question above, showing no records for  ie. 2012/09/26 2012 is correct and $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push() should also be triggered whether there are matched records or not, right? but the function is not triggered at all after the number of characters hit its limit.

Comment: you can try it on https://jsfiddle.net/4udkchf8/3/ which I've just created so that you can replicate the issue. When you enter upto to `2008/09/26 20`, you see the value is logged to the console but any characters after than ie. '2008/09/26 201...`.

Comment: _"showing no records for ie. `2012/09/26 2012` is correct"_ - that is not what happens with the DataTables example link you gave. That filter input causes one record to be displayed - as it should do. And the Fiddle you provided works the same way: If I enter `2008/09/26 2008` it correctly shows one record. But if I enter `2008/09/26 201` then it correctly shows zero records - and from that point onward you will _correctly_ no longer see anything logged to the console, because the function can no longer filter anything any further: there is no more data to filter.

Comment: The DataTables utility `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search` is still running - but it will never call your anonymous function (the one that you `push`ed onto its search array, and where your logging statements are). It will only start to call your function again when you have erased sufficient characters from your search term so that there is at least one row re-displayed. I can understand why this may seem counter-intuitive or even wrong, but that is how the DataTables search utility works, in this case.

Comment: @andrewjames thank you very much, I apprecaited that. any work around to get it work ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What "it" are you referring to? The filter is working correctly. There is no character limitation. What exactly are you trying to do that you cannot do? It is not clear. If you want your anonymous function to trigger when there is no data, then you cannot do that, without changing how the DataTables product is written. But why would you want your anonymous function to trigger in this situation? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can see that your Fiddle has a problem because it sorts each column whenever you try to use a filter input. But that is a completely different issue, which you can fix by looking at how [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) separates filtering from sorting..